# I want to stop machine from entering sleep/hibernate mode using a service

Tags: c#, windows-services, sleep-mode

I could do this in console app by setting SetThreadExecutionState and machine is not going to sleep/hibernate mode as long as the application is running. But in service, it's not working. As some people suggest I tried making SetThreadExecutionState setting at continuous intervals(1 minute) less than my system time out for sleep(2 minutes).

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT _PowerRequestContext;
    IntPtr _PowerRequest; //HANDLE

    // Availability Request Functions
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr PowerCreateRequest(ref POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT Context);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool PowerSetRequest(IntPtr PowerRequestHandle, PowerRequestType RequestType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool PowerClearRequest(IntPtr PowerRequestHandle, PowerRequestType RequestType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    // Availablity Request Enumerations and Constants
    enum PowerRequestType
    {
        PowerRequestDisplayRequired = 0,
        PowerRequestSystemRequired,
        PowerRequestAwayModeRequired,
        PowerRequestMaximum
    }

    const int POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_VERSION = 0;
    const int POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_SIMPLE_STRING = 0x1;
    const int POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_DETAILED_STRING = 0x2;

    // Availablity Request Structures
    // Note:  Windows defines the POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT structure with an
    // internal union of SimpleReasonString and Detailed information.
    // To avoid runtime interop issues, this version of 
    // POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT only supports SimpleReasonString.  
    // To use the detailed information,
    // define the PowerCreateRequest function with the first 
    // parameter of type POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_DETAILED.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT
    {
        public UInt32 Version;
        public UInt32 Flags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string
            SimpleReasonString;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PowerRequestContextDetailedInformation
    {
        public IntPtr LocalizedReasonModule;
        public UInt32 LocalizedReasonId;
        public UInt32 ReasonStringCount;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string[] ReasonStrings;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_DETAILED
    {
        public UInt32 Version;
        public UInt32 Flags;
        public PowerRequestContextDetailedInformation DetailedInformation;
    }
    #endregion



    /// <summary>
    /// Prevent screensaver, display dimming and power saving. This function wraps PInvokes on Win32 API. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enableConstantDisplayAndPower">True to get a constant display and power - False to clear the settings</param>
    private void EnableConstantDisplayAndPower(bool enableConstantDisplayAndPower)
    {
        if (enableConstantDisplayAndPower)
        {
            // Set up the diagnostic string
            _PowerRequestContext.Version = POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_VERSION;
            _PowerRequestContext.Flags = POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_SIMPLE_STRING;
            _PowerRequestContext.SimpleReasonString = "Continuous measurement"; // your reason for changing the power settings;

            // Create the request, get a handle
            _PowerRequest = PowerCreateRequest(ref _PowerRequestContext);


            // Set the request
            PowerSetRequest(_PowerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestSystemRequired);
            PowerSetRequest(_PowerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestDisplayRequired);
        }
        else
        {
            // Clear the request
            PowerClearRequest(_PowerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestSystemRequired);
            PowerClearRequest(_PowerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestDisplayRequired);

            CloseHandle(_PowerRequest);
        }
    }

 public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
   
        string sSource = "Service1";
        string sLog = "Application";
        string sEvent = "Sample Event";

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 60000;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sSource))
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog);

        EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent);
        EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent,
        EventLogEntryType.Warning, 234);
    }


    public void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs 
     e)
    {

        EventLog.WriteEntry("Service1", "In timer_Elapsed");
        EnableConstantDisplayAndPower(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just disable hibernation from your control panel? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Show `EnableConstantDisplayAndPower()`.

Comment: No we have to do that in client machines and it should be stopped from sleep or hiberante when only my service is running.

Comment: i can understand not wanting sleep/hibernate from inactivity but due to powerloss or machine lid shut etc this strikes me as bad and could end up in frequent occasions of machines shutdown forcefully ..

Comment: Enforcing specific settings is much easier with a group policy.

Comment: This is a peculiar requirement. It could easily leave a user feeling helpless. Services are *meant* to sit in the background and not interfere with the interactive side of windows. And that includes not interfering with sleep/hibernate functionality. Why is your service *so important* that it should interfere with normal use of Windows?

Comment: Actually, we provide a offline vendor online availability. We do install our service in their machines so that our service gets data from offilne vendor database and sends data over internet. There are many offline vendors and not everyone will be okay with changing group policy settings. Usually, during night time these machines are going into sleep mode in some of the cases only for some vendors. It's machine power goes off we can't stop it anyway. If we do this with a service once machine gets started automatic services will be started so that our prevent sleep will be enabled as long as..

Comment: it is up and we can disble it in our service  on stop.

Comment: Right, so you acknowledge that you cannot prevent power loss from stopping you from doing your work. Are you able to further move things around so that *you can recover smoothly when restarted from power loss/sleep/hibernate*? You need that functionality *anyway* for the power loss scenario so maybe work *with* the system rather than trying to fight it.

Comment: It's a service that sends data at every time interval so there is no loss if one request fails with power loss. It's ok whenever machine up service starts again it sends the data. There is no loss of work. for few cases we have way to process failed requests.

Comment: Hi Damien i did not get your point 'maybe work with the system rather than trying to fight it'. What do you mean by that?